# C# publish Web Core App to Azure problems with external login (Google Api)

Tags: c#, azure

i developed an application with the DotNet Core Web Technology on my computer with an external login with Google. Locally the application works. After publishing the application to the azure, I noticed, that I can not login on azure with my google account. I debugged the app and noticed, that the ExternalLoginAsync function returns null. Therefore I can not login with my external account. Afterwards i looked at the network stream and detected that the signin-google page is requested from google with the parameter "&prompt=none". If i look at the network stream on my local computer, I see that the paramter is "&prompt=consent".

My Configurations looks like that:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)                 
.AddGoogle(google =>                 
{                     
    google.AccessType = "offline";          
    google.SaveTokens = true;                     
    google.ClientId = "xxxyy";                     
    google.ClientSecret = "xxyyyytt";                                      
});
```

Does anyone know, why the external login is not working?

Best regards

Comment: You've configured the app correctly? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: My Configurations looks like that:
`services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddGoogle(google =>
                {
                    google.AccessType = "offline";
      google.SaveTokens = true;
                    google.ClientId = "xxxyy";
                    google.ClientSecret = "xxyyyytt";
                    
                });`

Comment: For me that sounds like a configuration problem and I'd double check your app config in google settings. Afaik that's the place where the prompt behavior comes from. But have to say I never integrated google...

Comment: are you using `https` in ur azure web server? if no, you have to enable `https`, I believe.

Comment: Thank you for all answers. I'm using https on azure web server.